# How to view webhook request?

Tags: webhooks, docusignapi

I have a webhook setup to receive notifications for a variety of reasons. (I'm still just testing the waters with DocuSign, so I simply created a catchall webhook.) My Django webserver is complaining that the request is using an unsupported media type. Is there a way to view the request DocuSign is sending to my server? The failure logs on the admin site doesn't show me the actual request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Temporarily set the url for the webhook to be an address at [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/). You will then be able to see the complete incoming webhook posts from the platform.

Then use an online xml pretty printer to easily understand the different parts of the incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

Docusign throws xml data to your webhook. In my case I captured it and saved it as xml files. Here's a portion of the code I wrote in PHP.

```
$postedXml = file_get_contents("php://input");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($postedXml);
```